# travelling salesman

Tags: algorithm, traveling-salesman

Where can I find source code for travelling salasman problem?

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/traveling-salesman ?

Comment: @Woot4Moo: the travelling salsaman problem is just as interesting.

Comment: you can solve it using ILP solver (formulation here:http://en.algoritmy.net/article/48915/Travelling-salesman). Ur use some heuristic, if the map respects triangle inequality

Answer (score 8):

nowhere, it's not been solved.

Comment: where can i find the code for p=np

Answer (score 1):

You had mentioned that you were having problems with more than 8 or 9 nodes.  This isn't surprising because the complexity increases exponentially with each added node.

[image]

As a result many solutions involve Genetic programming to gradually evolve a *good* answer.  Finding the *best* generally requires a brute-force check of all possibilities.
One example is [here](http://www.lalena.com/AI/Tsp/), which also provides their source code.